# wordpress admin-ajax.php always returning 0

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Ok I feel that I have set this up correctly but I am still getting a return of zero when I make this ajax request, I feel like its probably a typo and for what ever reason I cant see it?

this is my php class file:

```
class class2 extends class1
{
    public static function init()
    {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('empty-ad-check', plugins_url('mc-error-alerts/js/mc-error-alerts.js'),array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'empty-ad-check', 'ajax_send', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
        add_action('wp_ajax_sendEmptyAd', array( $this,'sendEmptyAdCallBack'));
    }

    public function sendEmptyAdCallBack()
    {
        echo 'My name is david';
    }
}
```

And then this should link to this js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.post( ajax_send.ajaxurl , {action: 'sendEmptyAd', name: 'David'})
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log('ajax request says: ' + data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of hooks, `wp_ajax_`(admin only) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` (public).

In your case, you should probably use the public version:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sendEmptyAd', array( $this, 'sendEmptyAdCallBack' ) );
```

Please note also that the callback should end with `wp_die()`:

```
public function sendEmptyAdCallBack()
{
    echo 'My name is david';

    wp_die();
}
```

I ran your code in my env with these changes and it works.

UPDATE: Here's the full code:

**myplugin.php**:

```
class MyPlugin_Controller
{
    public static function init()
    {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        wp_register_script( 'empty-ad-check', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myplugin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'empty-ad-check', 'ajax_send', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ));
        wp_enqueue_script( 'empty-ad-check' );

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_sendEmptyAd', array( $this, 'sendEmptyAdCallBack' ) );
    }

    public function sendEmptyAdCallBack()
    {
        echo 'My name is david';

        wp_die();
    }
}
MyPlugin_Controller::init();
```

**myplugin.js**:

```
/*global ajax_send, console, jQuery */
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.post(ajax_send.ajaxurl, {action: 'sendEmptyAd', name: 'David'})
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log('ajax request says: ' + data);
        });
});
```

Comment: were you doing all of this within a plugin? for some reason I am still returning 0.

Comment: Are you calling `init()` of `class2` anywhere? I had to add it in my test.

Comment: Yea I'm adding it at the bottom of my master class (or class1) like so: include 'class2.php';
add_action( 'genesis_before_footer', array( 'class2', 'init' ));

Comment: I added my full code above. I guess the problem is that `genesis_before_footer` action is not called for the Ajax request. Notice how I call `init()` directly after the definition of `class2`.